# vsTest targets wrong .NET version

Tags: azure-devops, xunit, vstest

My Azure DevOps build pipeline has a vsTest task in it. The test is specified in `azure-pipelines.yml` like so:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    arguments: '/Framework:.NETCoreApp,Version=3.0'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

When running the build pipeline, no tests get run and when looking in the log I find this line: `Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 and platform X86`.
Why does it look for a version different than the one specified in the YAML-file and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the users suggests the following approach in the comments section of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops):

> You can for example add `otherConsoleOptions:/Framework:.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1` in the task to set command line
>   options for VSTest.exe